# Adding and Displaying Integers in a Label

Tags: swift

I'm making a scoring app where you can keep track of the score for different board games or such that you are playing. Here is the code I have so far.

```
override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreTotal: UILabel!


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if let number = Int(scoreTextField.text!){
        scoreTotal.text = "\(number)"
        }

    }
```

I want to be able to  type in the textfield and when the button is pressed it add both the previous number and the one in the textfield together and display the result in the label. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: Try This   let oldNumber = Int(scoreTotal.text!) , if let number = Int(scoreTextField.text!){
    scoreTotal.text = "\(number + oldNumber)"
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let number = Int(scoreTextField.text!){
    let previousScoreText = scoreTotal.text
    if previousScoreText == nil || previousScoreText.isEmpty == true {
        previousScoreText = "0"
    }
    scoreTotal.text = "\(Int(previousScoreText!)! + number)"
}
```

Comment: Please upvote if the solution helped you. @DoughnutMan